# Custom/dynamic categorizations in data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssas, data-warehouse

We are in the process of expanding our data warehouse and we've come to a conundrum that nobody on the team has been able to solve. I tried searching for answers on Google, but it's hard to get the right terms.

Essentially, the problem is this. We have a data warehouse that keeps track of items. We have to do a lot of reporting out of this data warehouse. A lot of reports are driven by categorizing these items and then aggregating data according to the categorizations. Some reports share categorizations, and some may have their own that are specific to the report. Even in that case, there may be subsequent reporting or analysis (ad-hoc) that will need to reuse these categorizations. And there will likely be a lot of these categorization schemes. Furthermore, these schemes may rely on data from more than one fact table in order to categorize an item (and item information spans multiple fact tables due to different grain).

Our initial plan was to have dimensions for these, one for each categorization, or perhaps a junk dimension with a column for each category. And that would be fine if the number of categorizations is likely to remain static. However, there will always be new reports and analytical needs. We don't want to have to change the schema and the ETL process every time we want to add a new categorization scheme. We might also want to change the logic for a categorization without having to reimport the data or rerun parts of the ETL to recalculate.

So our options seem to be as follows:

1. Just put the logic in report and analysis queries, even if that means copying and pasting categorization logic from query to query
2. Use the dimension approach, with its flaws
3. Have functions for calculating categories, which can be used in queries, but will be costly because they may have to do additional queries inside of them (bad performance)
4. Have views on top of the fact tables that include extra category columns; the views can more easily be changed than regular table schemas, and don't require modifications to the ETL process
5. Use some sort of bridge table scheme to implement a many-to-many mapping between categories and items in each category; this increase query complexity, but reduces scheme modifications to none; ETL would still need to be modified, but the modification could probably be in a smaller area (maybe a single query or procedure to update the category mappings)

We want this system to be accessible, such that users won't need to do much, if anything, more to access these categorization fields as they would to access regular fact and dimension fields. We also want to avoid having to make a lot of changes to the schema and ETL process every time a new categorization schema is added to the database.

So my question is, essentially, are there ways better than the five I listed that can be used to solve this problem? Are there variations on those five that more effectively solve the problem? Or is it just a hard problem that will require some degree of suffering? Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, so any feedback in that respect would be helpful too.

tl;dr: we need ways to have a lot of different categorizations of items in the data warehouse and are not sure of the most efficient, easily managed or easy to use system.

EDIT: additional info: we are using SQL Server, with SSRS as the primary reporting front-end, and SSAS as a secondary front-end for analysis or ad-hoc querying.

Comment: It's an interesting question, and I don't think there's any simple, obvious solution. I notice that your question makes no mention of buying or developing a reporting tool that's capable of handling these categories in the reporting layer, including possibly storing them as user-specific 'preferences' (most tools let users store their own reports anyway). Is this something you've already considered and investigated? You did mention copying and pasting queries, which suggests that your end-user tools are not very advanced (I may be wrong), in which case it could be a good area to investigate.

Comment: @Pondlife: The problem is that all sorts of people will be using this database, and we are trying to avoid a situation where a high priesthood maintains all reports and queries. Now, it may be that that is the right answer and our broad accessibility goal is a bad one. We're also not against developing or buying a good reporting tool, but it'd need to be worth it. If there really are tools that can handle these needs on the reporting end and they do a good job, I'd love to know about them. We're currently using SSRS and SSAS.

Comment: @Pondlife: and yes, many of the end users are not familiar with databases and queries. Part of our goal is make it so that they can access the database without having to learn SQL and other fancy concepts. To some extent, though, this issue really is one of policy, not design. But I want to pick a design that will enable an effective policy and pick a policy that makes sense.

Comment: No central "priesthood", but on the other hand users "won't need to do much"? Who will actually do the work? :-) But yes it's difficult, a lot depends on user expectations, company culture, business needs etc. Personally I would identify 'global' categories that are widely used and must be consistent, a [mini-dimension](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/09/01/design-tip-127-creating-and-managing-mini-dimensions/) would be my first idea for them. For 'local' categories I would try to find a way to let end users manage them, preferably in the reporting tool or a custom tool as the last resort.

Comment: @Pondlife: can you explain how a reporting tool might manage these? Or rather, what kinds of reporting tools actually do that sort of thing? Thank you for being the only person to respond, by the way.

Comment: I just want to second everything Pondlife has stated in the comments...this is "just a hard problem that will require some degree of suffering".  And I like the idea of two versions: global static categories (via regular dimension) vs local dynamic categories (via M2M bridge)....especially if you can analyze your user/reporting needs and determine that the vast majority of reports/analysis revolve around the handful of global categorizations...

Comment: Without research I have no real idea (we use Business Objects, FWIW). How are categories defined? Which attributes are used, how complex is the logic? You could create 'computed' attributes in the reporting layer that are derived from 'real' attributes in the SQL data; or create a mapping in Excel and join the .xls file with the SQL data (BO supports joining mixed data providers); or create a mapping in a permanent database table and provide the user a way to upload/edit that table. There are just too many variables for anyone to say what the 'right' answer is for you, if there even is one.

Comment: @Pondlife: categories are defined by a variety of attributes that already exist as regular dimensions or facts. The computations are generally simple (if item's DimA = foo and DimB = bar, then category 1, else if item's DimA = baz, then category 2, else category 3), and within a categorization, items will be fully partitioned into exactly one of the categories (no more, no less).

Comment: @siride It sounds to me that if categories are based on existing dimensional attributes, then it makes the most sense to allow the users to define them as needed in the BI reporting layer, either via existing functionality (saved filters/prompts, etc) or with a custom tool that lets them define them. It depends on what your BI tools that you are using are.

Comment: @NWest: we're using Microsoft's stack: SSIS/SSAS/SSRS plus SQL Server. Not my decision, but it's likely not changing, except that we'll probably be adding SAS tools at some point in the near future to augment the Microsoft stack. Maybe the SAS tools do what you say, in which case, the issue is more or less solved (but I can't mark a comment as an answer!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments above, your best bet would probably be to build a small little .NET app or web app that allows the users to define categorizations themselves based on dimensional attributes.

You could define categories in a "Category Table"

```
CategoryID  
Category Name
```

You would then build a set of "mapping" tables that essential create a snowflake off each dimension to a category:

Category - Dim1 Mapping (CATEGORY_D1)

```
CategoryID
Dim1ID
```

Category - DimX Mapping

```
CategoryID
DimXID
```

Your little app would maintain and build these mapping tables as categories are defined.

When you build reports then, you define your joins between the Fact Table, Dim Tables, and Category Table.

If I wanted to find all items in Category 3, then I would write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ITEMS_FACT F
JOIN DIM1 D1 ON (F.DIM1_ID = D1.DIM1_ID)
JOIN CATEGORY_D1 CD2 ON (CD2.DIM1_ID = D1.DIM1_ID 
                         AND CD1.CATEGORY_ID = 3)
JOIN DIM2 D2 ON (F.DIM2_ID = D1.DIM2_ID)
JOIN CATEGORY_D2 CD2 ON (CD2.DIM2_ID = D1.DIM2_ID 
                         AND CD2.CATEGORY_ID = 3)
```

This would allow users to define any category they wanted, and there are no ETL changes at all (unless you have SCD type 2s - you may need to apply categories when the rows are updated).

If there are categories that manage "exceptions", you may need to build one category mapping table with all the dim combinations on them:

```
CategoryID
Dim1ID
Dim2ID
Dim3ID
```

You would then let the users define the logic in their tool (If Item has Dim1 Attr2 = 'A' and Dim2 Attr3 = 'B' then category 1), and then the mapping table is built based on that.

Your join would be a bit simpler then - just join the dims & fact to the category mapping on the dimension keys.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ITEMS_FACT F
JOIN DIM1 D1 ON (F.DIM1_ID = D1.DIM1_ID)
JOIN DIM2 D2 ON (F.DIM2_ID = D2.DIM2_ID)
JOIN CATEGORY_MAP CM ON (D1.DIM1_ID = CM.DIM1_ID 
                         AND D2.DIM2_ID = CM.DIM2_ID
                         AND CD1.CATEGORY_ID = 3)
```

Comment: Note that this may have a performance impact, depending on the number of different combinations of mappings. If the category map and dims are small, but the fact is large, you should be ok, since the optimizer ought to join the dim keys with the mapping, then join the results to the fact.

Comment: So for the cube, I'd need to join all of these tables in, which is fine. Where it may not be so fine is for users building queries. It depends, of course, on whether we end up having users use SQL directly, or if they use something like SAS or some other front-end to access the database.

Comment: In the case of users writing SQL, you could map a view on top of the fact with the dims and categories pre-joined - it may solve most of their issues.

Comment: that's what I was coming to as I've been rolling this around in my mind. I think your answer is the best, and the caveats from the other comments have been helpful as well. As it happens, we are probably going to use SAS for a lot of our end-user reporting and analysis, so we really can let the tool do the job. For the stuff that's not in SAS, your solution will probably work fine.